# Read file into pandas dataframe (using soh to split data)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Question:

I have seen some websites about how to read files into dataframe but can't find one that teach me how to read file that use soh to split data.

The files I get don't have extension but they look like .txt file.

For now I read the files row by row to create dataframes and it takes lots of time. Is there any way to make it faster?

## Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
openfile = open('filename','r')
column1 = []
column2 = []
for line in openfile:
    line = line.strip().split('\x01') #soh equals to '\x01'
    column1.append(line[0])
    column2.append(line[1])
data = {'column1':column1, 'column2':column2}
table = DataFrame(data,columns = ['column1','column2'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data doesn't have headers, this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_table('filename', sep='\x01', header=None, names=['column1','column2'])
```

You can rear more about reading files [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html#parsing-options).